# Distance between two skew lines in a cube

Tags: geometry

Let ABCD.EFGH be a cube with length 2. X is the midpoint of EF. Find distance between AX and BH.

I have no idea how to do this.[image]

Comment: Have you tried parametrizing the two line segments, then getting squared distance, then applying calc?

Comment: Another way is to find the (unit) vector perpendicular to both lines. And then, draw a picture, pick one point on the first line and one point on the second line arbitrarily. Now figure out what to do next.

Comment: Thanks all. But this problem actually come up in chapter about cube, before this I Iearned about distance between point and line and we can solve them by only phytagoreans theorem. So I thought this one will be around the same thing. Im still in highschool btw

Comment: Honestly not sure how to do this without vector methods. Is it possible to do such calculations with pure geometry?

Answer (score 2):

Let $D$ be the origin of the Cartesian coordinates, with $A(2,0,0)$, $B(2,2,0)$, $H(0,0,2)$ and $X(2,1,2)$. Then, the line equations for $AX$ and $BH$ are
$$AX: \>\>\>\vec {a}_1+ t\vec{b}_1=( 2,0,0)+t(0,1,2)$$
$$BH: \>\>\>\vec {a}_2 + t\vec{b}_2=( 0,0,2)+t(2,2,-2)$$
Note that the init vector perpendicular to both lines is
$$\vec n = \frac{\vec{b}_1\times \vec{b}_2 }
{|\vec{b}_1 \times \vec{b}_2|}= \frac1{\sqrt{56}}(-6,4,-2)$$
Then, the distance between the two lines is
$$d=|(\vec{a}_1-\vec{a}_2)\cdot \vec{n}
|=\frac{2\sqrt{14}}7
$$

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

With $(i,j,k)$ unit vectors along the axes consider vector cross product

$$(i + 2 k) \times (-2i+2j+2k)$$

which lies parallel to minimum distance vector between the given skew line vectors. Identify the points on the two skew lines. There are no parallel lines given here.

Comment: The result of your cross product technically “points in the same direction as [the vector that joins the two skew lines with minimum distance]”. It doesn’t “lie along the minimum distance”. But we are talking about the same thing, and this is just a pedantic issue.

Comment: Thanks,it was in a vector sense, shall correct the word.